# Multiselect attribute The value of Admin must be unique

Tags: magento2, attributes, attribute-options

I upgraded magento2 to 2.1.6
When I try add option to multiselect attribute i see message: **The value of Admin must be unique.**
How can I fix it?

Comment: plesae check if unique option set as true

Comment: @PankajPareek http://screenshots.collabstar.com/ao/121.png